# How to just include the rangeslider from jQuery Mobile?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, rangeslider

I'll use the range slider for my website from jQuery Mobile. The problem is that I've also other controls on my website that I'll use from bootstrap.

The `.rangeslider` is the only thing I'll use from jQuery Mobile. The `select.form-control` I'll use from bootstrap.

My question is how could I exclude all the things of jQuery Mobile except the `.rangeslider`?

I've looked to the official site of jQuery Mobile but only fond a link to download all the components not just the rangeslider.

Below is my code. See also the result to see the error.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<p>This is oke</p>
<div data-role="rangeslider"> <!-- Rangeslider form JQuery mobile -->
  <label for="price-min">Price:</label>
  <input type="range" name="price-min" id="price-min" value="200" min="0" max="1000">
  <label for="price-max">Price:</label>
  <input type="range" name="price-max" id="price-max" value="800" min="0" max="1000">
</div>

<hr/>
<p>This is not oke</p>
<select class="form-control"> <!-- form-control from bootstrap -->
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use Download Builder to download only what you need rather than everything. See this link http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/.

It allows you to customize the download by selecting the specific modules you need.